# Export Data from GraphenDB to import locally

Tags: import, neo4j, export, graphenedb

Does anybody know how to import the data from GraphenDB into a local DB? The export from graphendb.com gives a zip file with a lot of files. I am not sure how to import those into a local instance of neo4j. Below are some of the contents from the zip folder:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the contents of that zip file into `path/to/neo4j/data/graph.db` in a local instance of Neo4j. Then restart the Neo4j server.

Or, if you are using the desktop Neo4j application, just click "Choose" and point it to the extracted archive.

[image]

Comment: Sweet. I was using 2.2.5. I upgraded locally to the latest and got the popup as you suggested. Everything is good now. Thanks